# How do I install wireless drivers and firmware on Kali Linux

Tags: drivers, kali-linux, firmware

PLEASE NOTE: NO INTERNET ACCESS (No ethernet card).

My Network Card is:

```
Broadcom Corporation BCM4352 802.11ac Rev03
```

I don't even know where to download the firmware or drivers.

I use a Dell XPS 13.

```
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

I did this code to install and get this reply:

```
root@kali:~# apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 broadcom-sta-dkms : Depends: dkms (>= 2.1.0.0) but it is not going to be installed
 linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-amd64 : Depends: linux-headers-4.3.0-kali1-common (= 4.3.3-5kali4) but it is not going to be installed
                                   Depends: linux-kbuild-4.3 but it is not going to be installed
                                   Depends: linux-compiler-gcc-5-x86 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install the [`broadcom-sta`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/broadcom-sta) drivers:

```
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

(this will install the driver's source code, your kernel's support headers, and build and install the kernel module).

You appear to be running an older kernel, so the required headers and support packages are not longer available from the repositories. You'll need to upgrade your kernel too (this will also give you better hardware support):

```
apt-get update
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms linux-image-4.6.0-kali1-amd64 linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64
```

You'll probably want to upgrade the rest of your system while you're at it:

```
apt-get upgrade
```

and obviously you'll need to reboot to use the new kernel.

If you don't have Internet access things get a little more complicated. You'll need to download [`linux-image-4.6.0-kali1-amd64`](http://http.kali.org/pool/main/l/linux/linux-image-4.6.0-kali1-amd64_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb), [`linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64`](http://http.kali.org/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-amd64_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb), [`linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common`](http://http.kali.org/pool/main/l/linux/linux-headers-4.6.0-kali1-common_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb), [`linux-compiler-gcc-5-x86`](http://http.kali.org/pool/main/l/linux/linux-compiler-gcc-5-x86_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb), and [`linux-kbuild-4.6`](http://http.kali.org/pool/main/l/linux/linux-kbuild-4.6_4.6.4-1kali1_amd64.deb) for a start, and install them using `dpkg -i`. I'm hoping that will be enough (although I doubt it) — if it's not, you'd be better off finding an Ethernet cable to connect your laptop and use `apt-get` as above.

Comment: I did what you said, read my update. What do I do now?

Comment: What you do now is actually do what I said: you dropped the `linux-headers-` part of the command line...

Comment: apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms linux-headers-$ 4.3.0-kali1-amd64


_________Like this?

Comment: No, just copy and paste! `apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Ok, I did that and I get the reply I made in the edit above. Thankyou so much for ur help!

Comment: I've spent days on this, this is not working, it's driving me mad.

Comment: I can understand the frustration...

Comment: So I updated the response above, I'm missing dependencies, what do you recommend I do? Given no internet access

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about the "given no Internet access" part; so my update doesn't cover that, let me see...

Comment: I can't do any of that because no internet access, all commands say needs dependencies.

Comment: I've edited my answer again, now I'm off to bed, I'll pick this up again tomorrow!